# Class 'standalone' and linebreaks for a 'Je suis Charlie'

Tags: line-breaking, standalone

I have produced a *[Je suis Charlie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Je_suis_Charlie)* image, and I wanted initially to use the `standalone` class, but I did not obtain the intended result.

Here is the intended result:

[image: Je suis Charlie]

Here is the produced result:

[image: Je suis Charlie, no line break]

Here is the code:

```
% -*- coding: iso-latin-1; -*-

\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}
\pagecolor{black}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\begin{document}
%\Huge

\textcolor{Gray}{JE SUIS}
\bfseries
\textcolor{red}{CHARLIE}

\mdseries
\textcolor{Gray}{JE SUIS}
\bfseries
\textcolor{red}{POLICIER}

\mdseries
\textcolor{Gray}{JE SUIS}
\bfseries
\textcolor{red}{JUIF}

\mdseries
\textcolor{Gray}{JE SUIS}
\bfseries
\textcolor{red}{MUSULMAN}

\mdseries
\textcolor{Gray}{JE SUIS}
\bfseries
\textcolor{red}{ATHÉE}

\mdseries
\textcolor{Gray}{JE SUIS}
\bfseries
\textcolor{red}{FRÉDÉRIC}

\mdseries
\textcolor{Gray}{JE SUIS}
\bfseries
\textcolor{red}{AHMED}

\mdseries
\textcolor{Gray}{JE SUIS}
\bfseries
\textcolor{red}{YOHAV}

\mdseries
\textcolor{Gray}{JE SUIS}
\bfseries
\textcolor{red}{FRANÇAIS}

\mdseries
\textcolor{Gray}{JE DEMEURE}
\bfseries
\textcolor{white}{LIBRE !}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to use the `varwidth` option.

Comment: @AlanMunn indeed, this does it! didn't know about that. Thanks.

Comment: @AlanMunn I did not ask you to promote your comment into an answer, because yours is also mentioned there in comments, and the `tabular` + `package array` approach of the already provided answer, which has attracted a number of upvotes, has its advantages, hence I accepted it. But in my use case (for adding a `Je suis chrétien` some people told me found was lacking), I used your `varwidth` option proposal.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`standalone` does not really provide a paragraph mode, you better enclose everything in a `tabular`. You can, moreover, save yourself a lot of typing ;)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{color}
\pagecolor{black}
\usepackage{dejavu}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
%\Huge
\begin{tabular}{>{\color{Gray}JE SUIS\ \color{red}\bfseries}l}
CHARLIE\\
POLICIER\\
JUIF\\
MUSULMAN\\
ATHÉE\\
FRÉDÉRIC\\
AHMED\\
YOHAV\\
FRANÇAIS\\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\color{Gray}JE DEMEURE
\color{white}\bfseries LIBRE !}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

<sub>*(Text used in this answer doesn't necessarily express my opinion.)*</sub>

Comment: Or use the `varwidth` option, that allows ``\\`` for the line breaks. But `tabular` is handier for avoiding formatting instructions.

Comment: @egreg Yeah, that works as well of course (and makes my first sentence partially invalid...).

Comment: @yo' I avoided the typing from copy-yanking in the Emacs buffer, but doing as you do is better, thanks.